# Error: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace XXXX

Tags: c#, web-services, reference, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use my service reference, and the project 
doesn't recognize one of the classes in the web service project.
This is my code:

```
  private EventsService.EventsWS ewsService = 
    new EventsService.EventsWS();
```

And this is the error:

```
The type or namespace name `EventsWS` 
does not exist in the namespace 'EventsService' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I tried to remove and add the service and its still not working..
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please add more info:
1) what is your namespace? 2) have you tried to clean your project? 3) can you add a picture of your references in the IDE?

Comment: 1) I dont have one 2) i don't have that option 3) what is the IDE?

Comment: integrated development environment like visual studio or eclipse

Comment: show us the namespace `EventsService`